# ServerAlias does not share session

Tags: apache, symfony, virtualhost, symfony-2.3

I have configured my web server in this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.loc
ServerAlias www.example.loc

DocumentRoot /var/www/example/web
<Directory /var/www/example/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
```

The problem is that if I go to example.loc and I login and then I access www.example.log the session is not shared.

it is as if accedessi to a completely different site!

This is my configuration security.yml:

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        switch_user: true
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            default_target_path: reserved_area_index
        logout:
          path: fos_user_security_logout
          target: homepage
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/[^/]+/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/[^/]+/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/[^/]+/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/[^/]+/reserved_area, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the cookie domain in config.yml:

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_domain: .example.loc
```

Comment: Thank you. But I can not access the login in this way.

Comment: Edit: sorry, my mistake! I had to also delete your browser cache!
Thank you!